# Oracle JAR to Intel JXE

Tags: java, jar

I'm trying to understand how car audio media works. I have read emmc, and found here **.ifs** file. By using IFSTool I have extracted all files from **.ifs** and found Intel **.jxe** file. OK I have decompiled **.jxe** file to Oracle **.jar** by using this tool: https://github.com/spacemeowx2/jxe2jar I have made editions, but is there a way to convert it back to Intel **JXE**? What tool/software should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation for `jxe2jar`](https://github.com/spacemeowx2/jxe2jar/blob/master/doc/jxe2jar.pdf), the reverse conversion can be performed using `jar2jxe`.

As far as I can tell, that tool is only (legally<sup>1</sup>) available as a part of various IBM commercial products; e.g. WEME J9.

Unfortunately, the relevant IBM documentation doesn't seem to be publicly available either.

---

<sup>1 - If you google for (say) "jar2jxe download" you may find download links from (ahem) "3rd-party sites".  But there are no guarantees that what you will get when you download will be 1) a legal copy, or 2) free from malware.   If you need to work on a codebase that was built using IBM proprietary tools, you are strongly advised to get a legal copy of the tools for yourself.</sup>